# I can't run Chrome Debugger in VS Code on Linux Mint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, linux-mint, chrome-debugging

Hi I've got a problem to run Chrome Debugger directly in VS Code. I'm working on Linux Mint. This is how my launch.json file looks like:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
   
   
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        
        
      
    }
]

}
```

Now i try to run debugger and error message says: Unable to launch browser: "Unable to find Chrome version stable. Available auto-discovered versions are: ["dev"]. You can set the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json to one of these, or provide an absolute path to the browser executable."

Following the sugesstion I've added runtimeExecutable to chrome executable like this:

runtimeExecutable:"/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome" and now error message says:

Unable to Attach to the browser.

Google Chrome is installed on my machine version: 83.0.4103.116-1.

Thanks for help in advance

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwxUr.png)
[Current Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zElxd.png)

Comment: do you have the chrome debugger installed? whats `pwa-chrome` ? it should be `chrome`if you have the chrome debugger installed

Comment: Yes of course i have chrome debugger extension installed. When it comes to pwa-chrome, that was auto-genereted in launch.json file after installing extension. I also tried with value chrome but then a connnection tries to execute on localhost not a local file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using Chromium on Linux Mint.
I solved the problem with

> debug.javascript.usePreview: false in VS settings,

as explained in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620878/problem-to-run-chrome-debugger-in-vs-code/62910909#62910909)

Comment: `debug.javascript.usePreview` is no longer available starting from VSCode 1.60.0. Check out options on how to use the legacy debugger in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69122112/1044637)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `webroot` property too try this

```js
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "pwa-chrome",
    "url": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

Comment: Changed configuration like this and error message says "unable to attach to the browser".

Comment: are you sure `"request"` is set to launch and not attach?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I added a screenshot above.

Comment: can you change to ` "runtimeExecutable": "stable"` and check? is google chrome launching from shell commands?

Comment: After change it came back to error:  "Unable to find Chrome version stable. Available auto-discovered versions are: ["dev"]. You can set the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json to one of these, or provide an absolute path to the browser executable.". What do you mean shell commands? What should i type in terminal? Google Chrome runs normally when i run from graphical environment.

Comment: Still any ideas?