# VS Code trying to open a website instead of a java file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot of issue]

Hello, I am getting this error when trying to run my java app in VS Code. I am trying to run an app that works with an instantiable class. This seems to only have started happening today for some reason.

I am a noob and will need some dumbed-down help, please.

I have tried the below links but they haven't helped:

[Problem to run chrome debugger in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620878/problem-to-run-chrome-debugger-in-vs-code) (This does not work for me)

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208050 (I did this and it doesn't change anything)

This comes up in my VS Code terminal:

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

Comment: So neither installing chrome on your machine or adding configurations `"runtimeExecutabe": "\the abosolute path to broswer\"` in launch.json worked for you? Can you post the smallest code snippets for me to reproduce your question if convenient?

Answer (score 0):

It is working now after powering off and back on. One of the above two links must have done the job. Sorry, lol.